# updating data of a single table from a form that generates data for multiple tables codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i am updating a table's data from a form that is generating data for multiple tables. so when i run the update function its giving me an error: **Undefined property: Package->dayplan**

the controller code:

```
function update($id){
    $package = Package::find($id);
    $package->update_attributes($_POST);
    redirect('admin/packages/');
}
```

the view code:

```
<div class="container">
    <?= form_open('admin/packages/update/'.$package->id) ?>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8 form-data">
            <ul>
                <li><?= form_input('title', set_value('title', isset($package->title)?$package->title:''))?></li>
                <li><?= form_input('type', set_value('type', isset($package->type)?$package->type:''))?></li>
                <li><?= $this->ckeditor->editor('description', isset($package->description)?$package->description:'') ?></li>
                <li><?= form_input('price', set_value('price', isset($package->price)?$package->price:''))?></li>
                <li><?= form_input('location', set_value('location', isset($package->location)?$package->location:''))?></li>

            </ul>
  <ul>
                <?php
                foreach($dayplan as $row)
                {?>

                <li><?= form_input('dayplan[day_no][]', set_value('day_no', isset($row->day_no)?$row->day_no:''))?></li>
                <li><?= form_input('dayplan[description][]', set_value('description', isset($row->description)?$row->description:''))?></li>

                <?php }?>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <?php
                foreach($image as $row)
                {?>

                <label><input type="file" name="images[]" value=""><?php echo $row->image_location; ?></label>
                <?php }?>
            </ul>
        <?= form_submit('', $btn, 'class="publish-btn"') ?>
    </div>
    <?= form_close() ?>
```

when i click the submit button, it posts all the data of the form to the package table and generates that error of undefined property.

Comment: Please share the attributes of the Package model.

Comment: It appears the problem is in the code for `Package`. Edit your question and include that library's code.

Comment: @DFriend The problem is in this line 
$package->update_attributes($_POST); see the $_POST is posting data from all the forms which is generating the undefined property exception. We need to specify this line for the package

Comment: The problem is in this line $package->update_attributes($_POST); see the $_POST is posting all the data from all the forms to the package table which is generating the undefined property exception. We need to specify this line for the package data only ... See to the view file you'll have an idea

Comment: Somewhere there is a line of code that is either trying to read or set a class property named $dayplan. Except there is no such property in the class `Package'. Show the code for the `Package` or at the very least the code for `Package::update_attributes()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its done we have to pass an array of attribute to specify the attributes for package:a $data array for package's attributes.

updated solution:

```
function update($id){
    $package = Package::find($id);
    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location')
    );
    $package->update_attributes($data);
    redirect('admin/packages/');
}
```